# C++ Create derived class with abstract base class method

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an abstract base class, `BaseClass`, which has some fields (but not all), that are included in the derived classes, `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2`.

> BaseClass.h

```
class BaseClass
{
private:
    int bmember1;
    int bmember2;

public:
    BaseClass();
    ~BaseClass();
};
```

For example, DerivedClass1 would not have additional members...

> DerivedClass1.h

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass1();
    ~DerivedClass1();
};
```

... but DerivedClass2 would, `dmember1` and `dmember2`.

> DerivedClass2.h

```
class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
private:
    int dmember1;
    int dmember2;

public:
    DerivedClass1();
    ~DerivedClass1();
};
```

Now, I want some method in `BaseClass` that I could construct either derived class with, dynamically, using something arbitrary, such as an Enum:

> SwitchEnum.h

```
enum Switch_Enum
{
    DERIVED_1,
    DERIVED_2
};
```

I want to use parameters to initialize the fields in the `BaseClass` with, but I also want to give some default value to the ones present only in the derived classes, that I can later change with a method, again, called from the `BaseClass`. So, something like

```
//(BaseClass.h)

//BaseClass constructor, initializingthe BaseClass's fields with the parameters
BaseClass(int param1, int param2)
{
    //params to bmembers
}

//Construct the appropriate derived class
static BaseClass* createBase(int param1, int param2, Switch_Enum selector);
{
    switch(selector):
    {
    //DerivedClass1 if DERIVED_1, 2 if 2, etc. 
    //use BaseClass(int param1, int param2) to set the BaseClass fields that are present in all derived classes
    //If derived class has additional fields, give default values to those as well
    }
}
```

And finally, to set the possible additional fields, do something like:

```
//(BaseClass.h)
virtual void changeDmembers(int dmember2val, int dmember2val)
{
    //if DerivedClass1, do nothing
    //if DerivedClass2, set dmember1&2 to dmember1&2val
}
```

Do you think this is at all feasible? Should I approach this differently? Should I have all possible fields already appear in the `BaseClass` and only use them in the derived classes that would have them (which doesn't seem too elegant to me)?

Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: What is the question? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: this is mtl;dr sorry

Comment: Base classes have no knowledge of members that only exist in derived classes. In fact, classes have no knowledge what-so-ever whether other classes derive from them or not.

Comment: Sorry! I guess I've gone a bit too much into the idea itself, while my main question is about if it's at all worth doing. Basically I'm wondering how I should go about creating an abstract base class and classes that inherit it and have some fields of their own, and then construct them from the base class dynamically. From what I've seen, people use factories for this, but I couldn't quite implement my own the way I wanted. I'd like a factory that uses parameters to initialize the fields in the super class and then based on subclass, initialize the ones those have, then set them later somehow.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you think this is at all feasible?

Yes.

> Should I approach this differently?

Most certainly. Look up the factory pattern using your favorite search engine.

> Should I have all possible fields already appear in the `BaseClass` and only use them in the derived classes that would have them (which doesn't seem too elegant to me)?

Your hunch is correct. That's not a good idea. A base class should not make any assumptions about classes derived from it. It should have exactly what it needs -- nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked into factory constructors earlier, but I couldn't figure out how to use parameters with them. Would I just have to write a parameterized constructor for the abstract class and just call that? And can I even do that if that function is pure virtual?

Comment: There are more than one method to parametrize a constructor used by a the factory pattern. One of the most generic ways will be to pass a `std::map<std::string, std::string>`. The constructor function for a specific derived type will look for items with specific keys. If they are found, it can pull the data from the map, If they are not found, it can return with an error.